# Не получается удалить элемент из двумерного ассоциативного массива (PHP)

Tags: php, массивы

Вот код:

```
<?php

function getSizeForLimit($a, $b){
    foreach ($a as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 's' && $value > $b) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $a;

}

$a = array(array("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "s" => 4.5), array("a" => 4, "b" => 5, "c" => 6, "s" => 27));
$b = 10;
$c = getSizeForLimit($a, $b);
print_r($c);
```

Не получается удалить двумерный массив содержащий значение 27 под ключом "s". Условный оператор срабатывает на ура, но метод unset не удаляет массив. Пожалуйста, объясните какую ошибку я допустил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что в `foreach` передаётся копия массива, а не ссылка на него. Поэтому выходов тут миллион. Самый простой и против которого многие будут: добавить на него именно ссылку

```
foreach ($a as &$array) {
               ^------- ТУТ
```

**второй** - делать проход через `for`

**третий** - вначале исходный массив положить в `$arrayCopy` и пробегаться по нему, а удаляться уже из исходного.

и ещё куча способов

---

Удалить именно массив можно так:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $value) {
        if ($key2 == 's' && $value > $b) {
            unset($a[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал через добавление ссылки. Но удалилось только число 27, что собственно и логично, как я сейчас понял, ведь я через unset($array[$key]) удалил только этот элемент, но нужно удалить весь массив в котором находится это число. Это возможно исходя из этой конструкции? Я понимаю, что видимо сделал дендрафикальный вариант решения своей задачи и нужно всё переделать, но пока не знаю как это сделать через for или может вообще можно через array_search. Пожалуйста, подскажите как убить массив, в котором находится это значение 27.

Comment: @lsv-resume.ru мммм.....удалить весь массив можно просто по ключу. добавил в конец ответа

Comment: Я запутался в key и key2 ) записал дважды key, и у меня не удалялось ничего. Вы мой герой)) Уже все глаза замылились, а задание хотелось доделать. Иногда очень нужна такая вот помощь. Спасибо Вам ещё раз ОГРОМНОЕ!